# Which show was the first to use concept art as the ending credits?

Tags: first-appearance, credits

In Disney+'s *The Mandalorian*, each episode ends with concept arts during the ending song. I don't know if this is a new film technique or not, but I've seen in first in *RWBY* and now in *The Mandalorian*. Where did it originate from?

Comment: ........................"RWBY"?

Comment: I think it's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RWBY), pronounced ruby.

Comment: Is this question regarding shows only, or films as well? The title and the body don't seem to agree.

Comment: @raj Really depends on the answer. I say shows because so far I only know of shows that consistently do this, but it's entirely possible that a movie started this trend so I am being purposefully ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Pixar, and later Disney, have used end credits to display alternate art and/ or storyboards. The first film I can find that does this is [WALL-E](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/), although in that film [the end credits](https://www.artofthetitle.com/title/walle/) continue the story rather than retelling it.